# Gravatar image url is wrong?

Tags: php, https, gravatar

I have this code that pulls a user's gravatar:

```
if( $current_user->ID == 0 ) {
    // Not logged in.
    echo '<p><img src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/img/wpb-default-gravatar.png" alt="תמונת פרופיל"></p>';
    echo '<p>רוצה למכור?</p>';
    echo '<p><a href="חשבון-חנות">פתח חנות</a></p>';
}
else {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $args = array(
        'height'    => 50,
        'width'     => 50,
        'class'     => 'gravatar',
        'scheme'    => 'https'
    );
    echo '<p>'.get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 50, '', 'תמונת פרופיל', $args ).'</p>';
    echo '<p>היי, ' . $current_user->user_firstname.'!</p>';
    echo '<p><a href="'.get_permalink(get_option("woocommerce_myaccount_page_id")).'">חשבון</a> <span>|</span> <a href="'.wp_logout_url().'">התנתק</a></p>';
}
```

The function `get_avatar` result link is this: **http://i2.wp.com/nivbook.odedta.com/wp-content/themes/total-child-theme-master/img/wpb-default-gravatar.png**

What is **http://i2.wp.com/** doing in that link and how do I get rid of it?

Thanks

Comment: the url looks very wrong, you should contact the author of your theme, or disable relevant plugins to make sure the fault is not with them

Comment: Do you have Jetpack installed and active? That's one of the domains it uses for its CDN to speed up image loading.

Comment: I don't have Jetpack, no. I'll contact the author, though, that is a wordpress function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the filename suggests, it's a default for when someone does not have a gravatar assigned. It is set up in your child theme and looks to be improperly set. You should search through the child theme files to find 'wpb-default-gravatar.png' and from there figure out what is adding the extra domain.

If this is a child theme you've purchased and not a custom one, I would highly recommend letting the theme author know and if you're able to solve the code problem, send them a pull request or the finished code with an explanation of what problem you were solving so they can include it in the next update.

Comment: I don't understand why the image is not loaded though, if you click that link it opens up in the browser and the image is visible, so why the <img> tag doesn't accept it?

Comment: What is the full HTML output? Perhaps your site settings enforce HTTPS, and since the image is on HTTP instead, it's being hidden or prevented from displaying for security reasons?

Comment: That's exactly the issue! what can I do?

Comment: Try turning off all of your plugins and check whether you still have the problem. If you do, it's probably a theme issue. If the issue disappears, turn on plugins one by one and test until you figure out which one it's coming from. Then contact the theme or plugin author - it's fastest if you find a fix and submit a pull request to their codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Gravatar comes from the people of Wordpress. I don't find it weird they serve a default gravatar (which is requested from a Wordpress site) from a Wordpress domain.

Why do you want to get rid of it ?

Comment: What? read the question again please.

Comment: I think your theme uses some function to filter your default avatar through gravatar or so, because as morganestes already said, it's a WP domain, also used by jetpack. Search for the get_the_avatar filter in your themes or plugin. That filter might be overriding it somewhere.

Comment: It's not even in the theme files, i'll contact the theme author anyway. Thanks.